# Can I reattach to terminals that show up in `ps`?

Tags: unix, terminal, shell

I am a unix noob using zsh on mac osx and playing with tmux.

I opened up a terminal window in iTerm2 then ran tmux. Once that was opened I created a few new windows with `ctrl+b c`. I then closed iTerm2. Afterwards I opened up iTerm2 again and ran `ps` and now I see something like this

> ```
>   PID TTY           TIME CMD 
> 73322 ttys000    0:00.19 -zsh
> 70385 ttys002    0:00.16 -zsh
> 67526 ttys003    0:00.12 -zsh
> 67570 ttys004    0:00.12 -zsh
> 67614 ttys005    0:00.13 -zsh
> ```

Is there a way I can somehow attach to those terminal windows again? Maybe using iTerm2 or tmux? I tried `tmux attach -t ttys000` but as I understand it, I need to be attaching to a named tmux session.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do `tmux ls` to list available sessions and `tmux attach -t session` to re-attach.

Comment: straight to the point, i like that